# Python scipy optimize fmin from matlab fminsearch error

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting this matlab function handle to python and am receiving this error (ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.) in python. I'm pretty new to python sorry if there is an obvious error.

In matlab:

```
P = [1 1; 6 1; 6 5]
fh = @(x) sqrt(sum((ones(3,1)*x - P).^2, 2))
[x,fval] = fminsearch(@(x) max(fh(x)),[0 0])
```

In python:

```
P = np.matrix([[1, 1],[ 6, 1],[ 6, 5]])
fh = lambda x:np.sqrt(sum(np.power((np.ones((3,1))*x - P),2),axis = 0))
xopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=fh,x0 = np.matrix([0, 0]))
```

The code works in matlab but not in python thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your matlab code, `fminsearch` is minimizing the `max` of `fh(x)`. In the Python code, therefore, the `func` passed to `fmin` should be the `max` of `fh` as well:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

P = np.array([[1, 1],[ 6, 1],[ 6, 5]])

def fh(x):
    return np.max(np.sqrt(np.sum((x - P)**2, axis=1)))

xopt = optimize.fmin(func=fh, x0=np.array([0, 0]))
print(xopt)
```

yields

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 3.201562
         Iterations: 117
         Function evaluations: 222
[ 3.50007127  2.99991092]
```